# UIImagePickerController not returning image, can I use the reference URL?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset, phimagemanager

For a very small portion of my users UIImagePickerController seems to fail at retrieving the selected images

Looking at logging I've set, the images keys (both originalImage and editedImage) are empty, the info result only has the referenceURL and mediaType keys

Since no one has sent me a test case and I haven't been able to replicate it, I'm trying to mitigate it with other methods

I want to use PHImageManager with the referenceURL in case the image keys are empty, but I don't know if this is the right approach, considering I need to add a Privacy notice about reading the Photo Library

I know about the new picker in iOS 14, this would be a legacy solution

Comment: A few things, none of help with your issue. First, for iOS 14+ `PHPickerViewController` is still a bit buggy. It spit out a ton of console chatter and refused to open some images until Beta 4, and it still appears to crash in certain situations - at least in my testing. Second, and maybe more relevant (but I don't think so), it's the *only* VC that *does not* need a privacy notice in your info.plist. Even for UIImagePickerController you'll need to add that privacy notice.

Comment: I accidentally managed to reproduce this scenario after I turned on iCloud sync for Photos and then tried to select a video from my other phone (on iOS 14). Still don't know how to fix it.